# Get input value from input in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

So, this is kinda difficult to explain, and also to search for.

My situation:
i have a webpage which allows users to fill up to 48 time fields, all these time fields are dynamically generated, each with an ID of their own, all in a div.

Now, the user also has the option to delete a field, in any place. In this case i want to re-order them all.
Example: user has timebox 1 to 8, removes 5.
6 becomes 5, 7 becomes 6, 8 becomes 7.
This should also count for the ID's.

Now, when a user deletes a box, i pick up all the divs in a specific div (DailyControls) and put them in an array. All of these divs have a class named timepicker.

Now i need to get the value from the input boxes which are now also stored in the array.

This is for creating the textboxes (with the div, some text infront and the remove button)

```
var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("ID", 'time' + boxID);

                newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Herrinering #' + boxID + ' : </label>' +
          '<input type="text" name="timebox' + boxID +
          '" id="timebox' + boxID + '" value="" class="timepicker" >' + '<img src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~") %>images/ico_delete.png" id="Delete'+ boxID +'" onclick="DeleteTime()"/>');

                newTextBoxDiv.attr("class", "timerdiv");
```

To remove them i am currently using the following:

```
function DeleteTime() {
            var id = event.target.id;
            var IdNO = id.replace("Delete", "");

            $("#time" + IdNO).remove();

            var elemdivs = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < $(".timerdiv").length; i++) {
                elemdivs.push($(".timerdiv")[i].innerHTML);
            }

            $('.timerdiv').remove();
            for (var i = 0; i < elemdivs.length; i++) {
                alert(elemdivs[i]);
            }
        };
```

in the alert i can see the input element, and also the div ect.
But i dont know how to get the value from there

Comment: for re-order, if they have the same classes and the id or number order is an integer, you can do a `each()` function in jQuery and replace the id o order attribute with an integer that starts counting from 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you provided this would probably work:

```
function DeleteTime() {
        var id = event.target.id;
        var IdNO = id.replace("Delete", "");

        $("#time" + IdNO).remove();

        var elemdivs = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < $(".timerdiv").length; i++) {
            elemdivs.push($(".timerdiv")[i]); // don't push innerHTML
        }

        $('.timerdiv').remove();
        for (var i = 0; i < elemdivs.length; i++) {
            alert($(elemdivs[i]).find('input').val());
        }
    };
```

Instead of inserting the innerHTML from your timerdiv into the you put in the timerdiv itself. Then when accessing it you `.find()` the input field inside of the timerdiv (`$(elemdivs[i])`) and then get the `.val()` from that.